# Android vibrations settings - red line under else?

Tags: java, android, settings, vibration, android-vibration

I have put this section of code in my Setting Activity, so if the vibration box in the xml file which is working is checked, vibrators will be turned on and if not they will be cancelled. However, there seems to be a problem with the else that won't let me run the app. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
  if (preference instanceof vibrateapp_checkbox=="true");
    Vibrator.vibrate(new long[] { 0, 200, 0 }, 0);
    Else if (preference instanceof vibrateapp_checkbox=="false");
    Vibrator.cancel();
```

Comment: Hi i changed it to else but there is still a red line that says "delete this token"??

Comment: Remove the semicolon (`;`) after the if's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not `Else` its `else`. java is case sensitive. moreover, the `else` is without `if` because you ended if by `(;)`

```
if (preference instanceof vibrateapp_checkbox=="true")
    Vibrator.vibrate(new long[] { 0, 200, 0 }, 0);
else if (preference instanceof vibrateapp_checkbox=="false")
    Vibrator.cancel();
```

moreover, this seems incorrect
`(preference instanceof vibrateapp_checkbox=="false")` since after `instanceof`, `type` is expected not value

you can correct it as

```
if (vibrateapp_checkbox.isChecked())
        Vibrator.vibrate(new long[] { 0, 200, 0 }, 0);
    else
        Vibrator.cancel();
```

Comment: Hi i changed it to else but there is still a red line that says "delete this token"??

Comment: what would you use instead of instanceof

Comment: what is vibrateapp_checkbox is it a checkbox?

Comment: <CheckBoxPreference1
        android:key="vibrateapp_checkbox"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:title="@string/vibrations" />

Comment: cheers but what is the problem here:if (vibrateapp_checkbox.isChecked())
    vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
          vibrator.vibrate(50);
      else
          vibrator.cancel();

Answer (score 0):

Java is Case sensitive . Use else not Else

```
  if (preference instanceof vibrateapp_checkbox=="true")
    {
        Vibrator.vibrate(new long[] { 0, 200, 0 }, 0);
    }
        else if (preference instanceof vibrateapp_checkbox=="false")
    {
        Vibrator.cancel();
    }
```